# Scanning multiple lines with spaces in C

Tags: c, scanf, whitespace

**This is a piece of code I got for homework >**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   double x;
   int m;
   char letter;
   char words[40 + 1];

   ///////

   printf("%f|%d|%c|%s|\n", x, m, letter, words);

   return 0;
}
```

I have to use only one line of code and only use scanf() and fill the place where backslahes are.
I have this kind of input (arrows are pressed enter and dots are spaces) >

```
8.95-49↵
···A··B↵
······abc defghi!!!↵
```

I need to get output like this >

```
8.950000|-49|A|abc defghi|↵
```

How should scanf() look like?

Comment: john, what have you tried for your homework?

Comment: Solve them one at a time. Get the first one right, ignoring the rest. When solved, move on to the next. To help you progress, redirect the whole of the given input from a file.